What is the fee for GCP Custom Image sharing between regions
I'm new to GCP and have some experience with both Azure and AWS.
In my work, need to have a custom image in one project and share it publicly across multiple regions.
In both AWS and Azure I have to explicitly replicate the image to a region to create an instance from it.
In GCP, I have a public custom image placed in one region, let's assume us-central1.
I successfully tried to create an instance from it in a different project and a different region, let assume europe-central2.
I believe this is documented here:
create instance in another region
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-custom#selecting_image_storage_location
I found this regarding the pricing of custom image storage:
custom image pricing
which states that there are no network transfer fees for creating images, nor for creating disks from images.
My main question is:
Is this correct? Are there really no network transfer fees also when creating the instance in another region?
Another concern I have is whether I should copy the custom image to all regions or not.
I tried to find documentation about cross-region custom image pricing but couldn't find any.

In the docs that you linked we can find:

When creating a custom image, you can specify the image's Cloud
Storage location, excluding dual-region locations.
(…)
If the image is not available in a region where you are creating a VM,
Compute Engine caches the image in that region the first time you
create a VM.

So you need to consider Cloud Storage pricing (especially Data transfer within Google Cloud) when you use images in another region. Docs says that the image is cached on the first usage so this transfer cost is paid only once I guess but I can't find the TTL of a cached image.
By default, the image is stored in a multi-region so if a VM will be created in a region that is part of the multi-region there shouldn't be any transfer cost when creating a VM from this image. But if VM will be created in the region which is not part of multi-region then you will be charged for this transfer.
